# copy constructor for derived class changing base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, derived-class

Let's assume I have following situation:

```
class NamedObject{
public:
    NamedObject(const std::string &name):name_{std::move(name)}{}
private: 
    const std::string name_;
}

class Person: public NamedObject{
public:
    Person(const std::string &name, int age): NamedObject(name), age_{age}{}
private:
    int age_;
}
```

I want to create a "copy constructor" where I copy all members from `Person` but change the name (for whatever reason).

```
class Person: public NamedObject{
public:
    Person(const std::string &name, int age): NamedObject(name), age_{age}{}
    Person(const std::string &newName, const Person &other): NamedObject(name){
        age_ = other.age;
    }
private:
    int age_;
}
```

Now assume I have not only one attribute like `age` but many attributes and they are changed a lot during development. Is it somehow easily possible to create a function like `Person(const std::string &newName, const Person &other)` without manually copying all attributes like `age_ = other.age;`. The idea is that during development I do not have to always recall to change this constructor if I add a new attribute.

Please note that I cannot simply change the name because it is `const`.

Comment: Don't make it const.

Comment: You could have a virtual function `getName()`, and also additional `string Person::nameReplacement`, and in `getName` you return either `Person::nameReplacement` or `NamedObject::name_`.

Comment: Aside, you are using `std::move` incorrectly.

Comment: sry about the `std::move` error... I know.

Comment: As a design decision, you should not need to make the member variable `const`, since it does not actually have the immutability semantics you'd want in C++.  Instead, just have it be private with a public getter and no setter, and it is effectively immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an assignment operator on `NamedObject` that does nothing. Then you would be able to use `*this = other` in the "copy constructor":

```
class NamedObject{
public:
    NamedObject(const std::string &name):name_{name}{}
    NamedObject &operator= (const NamedObject &) {
        return *this;
    }
    const std::string name_;
};


class Person: public NamedObject{
public:
    Person(const std::string &name, int age): NamedObject(name), age_{age}{}
    Person(const std::string &newName, const Person &other): NamedObject(newName){
        *this = other;
    }
    int age_;
};
```

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/rJ4J5oy3M

Why it works:

C++ will automatically define a copy assignment operator for *eligible* classes (check the following link for details on what *eligible* means). From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment#Implicitly-defined_copy_assignment_operator):

> If the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator is neither deleted
>   nor trivial, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and
>   compiled) by the compiler if odr-used. For union types, the
>   implicitly-defined copy assignment copies the object representation
>   (as by std::memmove). For non-union class types (class and struct),
>   the operator performs member-wise copy assignment of the object's
>   bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using
>   built-in assignment for the scalars and copy assignment operator for
>   class types.

Thus, for your example the implicitly defined copy assignment operator (the one that is called when we do `*this = other;`) will be defined as follows:

- it will use the copy assignment operator of `NamedObject` to copy the base class (which we defined to do nothing, so it won't copy `name_`),
- it will use the copy assignment operator for `age_` and any additional member you add to the class.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain why I need the assignment operator in `NamedObject`?

Comment: @user7431005 • because of the `const std::string name_;`

Comment: @user7431005 sure, I updated my answer to include the explanation

Comment: Also, as @Eljay noted, if you don't define your own assignment operator, the compiler won't synthesize one for `NamedObject` (because `name_` is constant, so it cannot be assigned to), and by extension it won't synthesize one for `Person` (because `NamedObject` doesn't have one).

Comment: Redefining the function of an operator in this way is a major code smell. Please don't do it. Kittens die when you think about doing it.

Comment: @Clearer depends on how you look at it, and how you use it. The question was about doing it as a temporary solution during development. Also it depends on what "name" represents. If it is an identifier of an object in code (maybe used for debugging, to see how many distinct objects exist), then it is perfectly understandable that copying an object shouldn't copy the object's name (the same as it doesn't copy the object's address).

Comment: Also, to whoever downvoted this response, I would appreciate if you explained why - I think this is a perfectly valid solution for the question. The question is not asking whether this is semantically correct, and I don't think it can be deduced from the example in the question that this is not correct semantics. It can only be **assumed** it is not correct (a "code smell" as @Clearer put it) at best.